# C# mongodb driver Find function takes long time to execute (16 minutes)

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker, nginx, .net-6.0

We are using .NET 6 web api inside docker container on linux. Our issue is that sometimes randomly mongodb driver Find() function hangs for 16 minutes. The function call does not fail. We are using mongodb atlas and mongodb driver v 2.15.1 from nuget.

I have tried debugging mongo with shell but there is not any ongoing queries when the find function is hanging.

Our request flow
Frontend => NginX => reverseproxy to web api that is in docker container.

The fun part is that when you use and navigate the web page continuously that calls the web api none of the request left pending/hanging but if you idle on the page for few minutes and again stat to use page and navigate one request goes to pending and hangs for 16 minutes.

Comment: check what happens in server logs

Comment: Try specifying `ReadTimeout` like with 1 min. Will it help?

Comment: Cant get logs because of the free tier of mongodb atlas tier. We got the same pending issue from other web api which is requesting the atlas database on c# .NET 6 and the hanging time was exactly same. 16 mins and +-10 secs. This webapi does not even has Nginx or dockercontainer which could make some twists to network traffic.

Comment: Try setting ReadTimeout first

Comment: We have having the same issue but ours is only a 13 minute delay. We are on AWS with VPC peering setup and running on Fargate in case that makes a difference. Did you end up finding a fix or get a response from Mongo on this problem or just gave up?

Comment: @Seer do you have appropriate indexes for your query? Are you pulling a lot of data? I've never seen this kind of problem with Mongo unless I've messed up.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama this is pulling a single record by ID. Index is there. This only happens on Atlas and is fine against mongo on our network and development environment. Same call to same collection for other jobs is fine. We got some read timeout before that that is gone. First insert of doc is fast but read it back hangers on Atlas only. I would love it to be my code and not mongo driver or atlas. Thought maybe connection string setting my be needed to fail faster and retry

Comment: @Seer There's got to be something else holding up your requests. Our entire service runs off MongoDB's Atlas and most of our Mongo response times are measured in milliseconds.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama i agree something is wrong. Atlas i normally great and i have been using Mongo for years. I am engaging Mongo Support as well it was jsut this original question matched my issue basically exactly. I was hoping someone may have found something or people that experience it in the future know they are not alone. if i get an answer from mongo support on it i will add it below as well

Comment: @Seer As a point of troubleshooting, I'd suggest seeing if you can run an explain on the query as it may point to your issues.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to get rid of MongoDB Atlas and instead run mongodb locally on a virtual machine. All the pending and hanging errors are gone now.

Comment: it's not equivalent replacement, but obviously it's up to you